# JS function that returns one array element at a time to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Im getting a timeout on my server because there is too much data for it to load, so im trying to make a js function that returns one 'symbol' at a time from 0 to about 2800 and then i want it to feed into my php code. 
I imagine it looking a bit like this just don't know how to make it pass only one at a time and then the next in line. Hope someone can help.

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        document.write(data[i]["symbol"] + "<br>");
    }

});
/*This returns my code like this:
A
AA
AAC
AAN
AAP
(And so on)
*/
```

I then want to give that function a $symbol in PHP

```
$url = "https://api.website.com/public/user/TOKEN/stock/$symbol/keyratios";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the function in `PHP`?

Comment: I have done that but there is WAY to much data so the only way to bypass that is to make it load one at a time instead of everything at once.

Comment: Hmmm... I would imagine it's possible to read one at a time in `PHP`. For the `JS` to work you'd probably need to also use `AJAX` too. Here's a php parser that might work: https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser. Actually there are a bunch, I just clicked the first one that came up :)

Comment: Thank you I will be looking at that now :)